# In C/C++, How to inplace edit a file?

Tags: c++, file

In general I read and edit a file in C++ with following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  char text[200];
  fstream file;
  file.open ("example.txt", ios::out | ios::in );
  cout << "Write text to be written on file." << endl;
  // Reding from file
  file >> text;
  cout << text << endl;
  // Writing on file
  cin.getline(text, sizeof(text));
  file << text << endl;
  //closing the file
  file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

but if the text file is very huge; say 2GB, and i just want to **change a single word** and save it, how to write a file so that only the sector with the edit is effected on the disc instead of rewriting whole file. How to inplace edit a file?

I have seen app called `subler` on macos to just add subtitles to a huge movie file and save it without rewriting entire movie file in just few seconds! so I knew inplace editing a file is possible.

Comment: It is much easier to in-place edit *structured* files than un-structured ones. And a text file is not structured. Long story short, only if the new word has exactly the same length as the old one, in-place edit will be possible. BTW, unless if you know the exact position of the word you want to change, you will have to sequentially read it up to that word...

Comment: `cin.getline(text, sizeof(text)); file >> text;` Please explain the purpose of this.

Comment: @SergeBallesta what is a structured file? how to in-place edit a structured file? please provide your answer. thanks.

Comment: @Necktwi like a doc, xls or database file. They allow random edits of objects inside them. And there's no "C/C++" language. Please update the title

Comment: there may not be such a thing as inplace edit depending on your case and what you mean by inplace.  it begins with opening your file as readwrite, and possibly enlarging your file.  In your shoes, I'd look at memory mapped files (if available) and let the OS handle the massive copying - which may not be avoidable.